# How to get BUFR Soundings using Siphon from the University of Wyoming?

Tags: python-siphon, bufr

By using the codes below, I can succesfully get “TEMP Soundings” data from the University of Wyoming. (The website is http://weather.uwyo.edu/upperair/sounding.html)

```
import datetime 
from siphon.simplewebservice.wyoming import WyomingUpperAir

date = datetime(2022, 3, 7, 0)
site = '54511'
df = WyomingUpperAir.request_data(date, site)
```

However, now the sounding data at some particular stations can only be obtained in the form of "BUFR Soundings", and the code "WyomingUpperAir.request_data(date, site)" does not work anymore. The website is http://weather.uwyo.edu/upperair/bufrraob.shtml
How can I get these data by using Siphon (or other tool)? Thanks.

Gary,
27 Mar 2022

Answer (score 1):

There's no support in Siphon for handling BUFR soundings.

You may have some success manually downloading the BUFR files and parsing with with [bufrtools](https://github.com/axiom-data-science/bufrtools) or [python-bufr](https://github.com/pytroll/python-bufr) (though that might not be maintained).

Comment: Another unmaintained alternative is [trollbufr](https://github.com/pytroll/trollbufr/).  There is also [pybufrkit](https://github.com/ywangd/pybufrkit).